# Storing data inside JWT token or fetching a fresh data every request

Tags: security, cookies, jwt, backend

In an attempt to secure a backend using JWT token over cookies.
It is not clear to me what data is safe to store inside the token/cookie.

for example in the specific case where a check of parameters like `policy role`, and `user license type` is needed.

will it be safe to store them inside the `JWT` token?
**OR**.
Store only the `user_id` and get a fresh data from the storage (`DB`/`memcached`)?

Thank you